# Has anybody been able to enable Code Coverage highlighting on WebStorm with Karma/Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, webstorm, karma-jasmine, istanbul, karma-coverage

Even though I can get the code coverage measurement (percentage o files and code lines covered by unit tests) working correctly, I can't make it highlight the covered code in the editor.

I have karma-coverage

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Added screenshots as requested. Sorry I had to blur some info.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8tz7.png)
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8tOf.png)

Comment: Screenshots please (of your whole editor area).

Comment: You are using some custom color scheme where such colors may be invisible/reset. Try with Default color schema first. Note that by default lines that are covered or not covered have no background color -- highlighting done in gutter area only (light colors; located somewhere next to VCS line status). If you want to see background colors -- you will need to edit your schema a bit (`Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General | Line Coverage` -- you need to remove foreground color (uncheck it) and setup bg colors instead). Obviously, try it for file/code area that definitely has lines covered

Comment: As an example (notice the light colors left to the line numbers) -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/_persistent/line-coverage-in-the-editor.png?file=74-157208&v=0&c=true&updated=1401303820523